# Dynamic subquery in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I love to build LINQ to entity queries dynamically. For simple a simple filter I do something like this:

```
var query = model.Pets;

if(searchForName)
   query = query.Where(p => p.Name == "Bello");

if(searchForType)
   query = query.Where(p => p.Type == 1);

var result = query.ToList();
```

Now, I want exactly this type of dynamic query building for a more complex query.

This is the new (sample) schema:

[image]

Is there a way to generate a resulting query to select all Pets but only include Owner with some properties?

The results should be:

```
model.Pets.Include(p.Owner);
```

or

```
model.Pets.Include(p.Owner.Where(o => o.Name == "Hans"));
```

or

```
model.Pets.Include(p.Owner.Where(o => o.Gender == 0));
```

or

```
model.Pets.Include(p.Owner.Where(o => o.Name == "Hans").Where(o => o.Gender == 0));
```

I didn't find a solution to inject a Where clause in the middle of a query.
The above sample is simplified, I need this for more complex queries with joins and subselects.

Comment: using `model.Pets.Include(p.Owner);` with the last 3 conditions doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well, it makes sense, but it isn't implemented and it throws exceptions.

Comment: Can't you just do `model.Pets.Include(p => p.Owner).Where(p => p.Owner.Name =="Hans" && p.Owner.Gender == 0);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the query syntax (which is, in my opinion, much easier to use) :

```
List<Pets> petsList = (from pet in model.Pets
join owner in model.Owner on pet.Owner_name equals owner.Name
where owner.Name.Equals("Hans") || owner.Name.Equals("James")
where pet.Type == 1
select pet).ToList();
```

Hope this helps.

PS : for primary key, prefer integer instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend you to user PredicateBuilder

please see the site http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

it'll be more easier to build your dynamic filters

you can even use methods

```
public static Expression<Func<Product, bool>> ContainsInDescription (
                                            params string[] keywords)

{
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();
foreach (string keyword in keywords)
{
  string temp = keyword;
  predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
}
return predicate;


var classics = Product.ContainsInDescription ("Nokia", "Ericsson")
                  .And (Product.IsSelling());
```